# MongoDb Count on dynamic Query really slow

Tags: sql, performance, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to query a database with more than 50 million records. The query changes every time it's taking so long to count the records. For the query below:

```
var query =
                    from e in this.collection.AsQueryable<SocialRecord>()
                    where e.TermMonitorIds.Contains(term) && sources.Contains(e.SocialType) && e.DateCreated >= fr && e.DateCreated <= to
                    select e;
```

I have created an index on

```
{
    "TermMonitorIds" : 1,
    "SocialType" : -1,
    "DateCreated" : -1
}
```

Is there anyway i can improve the performance?

Comment: Does this query have an index? An adhoc query like this may not be able to take advantage of indexes. You should look at the output from .Explain() on the cursor returned by the driver.

Comment: On which fields i need to create an index on? I created a compound index on "TermMonitorIds", "SocialType" ,"DateCreated"

Comment: @DheerajPalagiri: can you include output from an `explain()` on the query? There isn't enough information to understand why this query is slow. Also, what version of MongoDB are you using?